# refreshing / reloading the PartialView inside the current view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor, partial-views

I have a PartialView that is an image upload, and basically I am displaying some images and then the normal Upload buttons :-

```
@model MvcCommons.ViewModels.ImageModel

<table>
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src= "@Url.Content("/Uploads/" + item.FileName)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </td>
            </tr>    
        }
    }

</table>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "File", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="description" /> 
}
```

Now my idea is to have this in different pages.  I tried it in 1 page already and is working fine, however when I Upload an image,

```
public ActionResult ImageUpload()
{
    ImageModel model = new ImageModel();
    model.Populate();
    return View(model);
}
```

I want to go back to the "previous" View, ie the View that is hosting this partial view?  When I do `return View(model)` as above, I get into the `ImageUpload` partial view which I do not want to.

Thanks for your help and time.

****UPDATE********************
I went for the simple route for the time being, and hard coded the actual View name

```
public ActionResult ImageUpload()
{
    ImageModel model = new ImageModel(); 
    model.Populate(); 
    return View("~/Views/Project/Create.cshtml", model); 
}
```

however I got an error :-

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `MvcCommons.ViewModels.ImageModel`, but this dictionary requires a model item of type `MvcCommons.Models.Project`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the overload that takes a string of the name of the view you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460310

```
protected internal ViewResult View(
        string viewName,
        Object model
)
```

i.e.

```
return View("ViewName", model);
```

if you have this in different pages then you can inject context via the action paramaters;

```
public ActionResult ImageUpload(string parentViewName)
{
    ImageModel model = new ImageModel();
    model.Populate();
    return View(parentViewName, model);
}
```

NOTE: You should only need to pass the views name not the path:

```
return View("Create", model);
```

Comment: Hi Jflood, in which controller do I do that? ImageUpload cannot be so how can I get the previous View name? This partial View will be in different views.

Comment: added more info: give that last one a try, let me know if it works?

Comment: Hi Jflood, I tried the last one but the ParentActionViewContext was null.  I also updated my question, with the example you suggested above, however I hard coded it to make for the moment just to get it working.  Still an error though

Comment: I want to pass 2 models, though I think its not possible.  A model that is retreiving the projects, and anther model that is retreiving the images.  else I have to do one combined but then for every Entity I have since most of them will have images.

Comment: yea not sure what where the "Dictionary" u mention is in the code. Combine the models inside the action if thats what you require.

Comment: so basically there is no other way to display the PartialView inside of different pages?  I have to pre-populate the model with the entities and their images, according to the variable I pass in the Action.  Seems to be a bit too much for what i need I think

Comment: @Johann you can't pass two models from a controller action to View or vice-versa, you need to use a composite model for that, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720756/how-to-edit-two-or-more-models-in-a-single-view-page-asp-net-mvc3/10720834#10720834

Comment: If it's causing you too much trouble, maybe you need to rethink your design.

Comment: Thanks Alfalfa will look at the link.  Re-think my design.  Well i thought I could do the same as I used to do in normal ASPNET Web pages, ie an image upload controller and using it in different pages, guess in MVC is much more complicated!

Comment: @Alfalfa I looked at that example, but i guess in my case its better for me to add a List<Image> inside the Models that I need to show images and then I will have everything inside one model.

Comment: I agree, if you are talking about just multiples of an image, that works fine, but if the multiples were some more complex object you could even still do that and use a foreach and build the objects out. I got the impression you were editing 2 distinct objects only and needed to send them both to a view, in that case you use a composite

Comment: Isn't the question "I want to go back to the "previous" View, ie the View that is hosting this partial view? " have you tried my suggestion for passing the parent views name as a parameter of the action?

Comment: Actually Alfalfa you are right, I did find your approach much simpler, especially when coming to do complext editing on the images model. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.  I finished up creating another ViewModel for the Projects, and then a composite for the Images ViewModel and the Projects ViewModel.  I will also add the other entities in a similar fashion.

Comment: thanks Alfalfa, I did a +1 on Jfloods Answer, and accepted it as an answer, do I need to do any other +1? Sorry not used to stackoverflow that much