# MVC3 more strongly typed Model Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new in MVC3. When i create a strongly typed view it use this code at top on the view code file

```
@model MonoPoly.Models.LandDocument
```

so it means that view can use all property from that Model class (here this LandDocument model class). But my question is how can i user more model class as a strongly typed for this single view file ? OR how should i can call other model class property in this view which is already strongly typed with that LandDocument Model class ?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to edit multiple models in a single Razor View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720756/how-to-edit-multiple-models-in-a-single-razor-view)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to create a `ViewModel` object that contains all the objects you would like to reference in your view.  See the details of how to implement the ViewModel pattern on [Steve Michelotti's blog: Pattern 2 – Dedicated view model that *contains* the domain model object](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx)

For example, if you wanted both the `LandDocument` class and a `Player` class, you could create a `ViewModel` like this:

```
public class BoardViewModel
{
    public LandDocument LandDocument { get; set; }
    public Player LandOwner { get; set; }
}
```

and then at the top of your view:

```
@model MonoPoly.ViewModels.BordViewModel
```

You would access the data in your view with like this, for example:

```
@Model.LandDocument.LandDocumentId
```

Comment: Humm... Is that will be ok to make another mother view model call with all those model class property ?

Comment: Yes, this is a very common pattern and works well in many scenarios. For large, complex views it may be better to use "Pattern 3" described in the post, but that choice is largely dependent on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a composite View Model class that encapsulates all of the objects you need.

Example:

```
public class InvoiceViewModel
{
    public InvoiceHeader Header { get; set; }
    public List<InvoiceDetail> Details { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I can't understand your Answer can you make me understand withmore details ? please ?

Comment: The `InvoiceViewModel` example that I provided is what you would pass to your View.  You would refer to the Invoice Header as `Model.Header` and the Invoice Details as `Model.Details`.  You would refer to individual fields within these as `Model.Header.Name`, `Model.Header.Address`, etc.