# How to load edit fields from another view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on simple practice web app with 2 models: Company & Customer - both have their own views. In the Edit view for Company, I want to load the edit form from the Customer view so the user can update Company & Customer at once.

The Company/Edit view displays a list of customers (I loaded customers data using a view model for Company & Customer). There's an "Edit" icon next to each customer's name in the 'customer-info' div. Clicking the button will load editor forms from the Customers/Edit view onto the Company/Edit view.

Am I structuring this correctly or is there a better way to combine both model's data so that the user can edit them simultaneously?

Note: I am using MVC Entity Framework Core & Visual Studio 2017 to build this app.

Comment: One way you could do this is to create a combined Model for the new view that has both a `Customer` and `Company` in it. That way you can put both forms on the one page, have all your MVC validation (if you're using that) and when you submit the form you'll get a combination of the both Models to work with server-side

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a new ViewModel that contains the information from the Company and Customer you'd like to be edited

```
namespace Application.ViewModels
{
    public class CompanyCustomerViewModel
    {
      public string CompanyName {get; set;}
      public string CustomerName {get; set;}
      // Other Fields You'd Like Edited
    }
}
```

You could then create and load this object with the Company and Customer information in your Controller's edit method and pass the CompanyCustomerViewModel instead of a Company to the view.

Also see: [How to edit multiple models in a single Razor View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720756/how-to-edit-multiple-models-in-a-single-razor-view)

Comment: What if instead of public string CustomerName, I want to use public List<Customer> Customers. How can I initiliaze the database to contain & display every item in the Customers list (next to Company Name) in the view and also allow the user to edit customers individually?

Comment: If you're doing a One(company) to Many(customers) you can add a int property called <entity>Id inside your Customer model class. For example: public int CompanyId and then add a IEnumerable <Customer> Customers to your company class.

Comment: How do I pass this enumerable Customer entity to my DbInitiliazer class? For example,  new Company  {Name = "Some name", WebsiteLink="http://www.example.com",  ContactNo="800-293-2091", Email="info@example.com", Customers = ... }